# selenium: type_keys(locator, "movyt") not typing correct value

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am using firefox
I Have used the following code in selenium:

```
selenium: type_keys(locator, "movyt")
```

But this types on `mov` and then clicks on the 'Tools' dropdown menu on the browser. 
I found that this is because y is treated as F10 and then t is treated as clicking on 'Tools' and hence the problem.

But is there a way to correctly type 'movyt' using type_keys() in selenium?
Thnaks

Comment: interesting...can't you just use type instead of typeKeys?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar was happening to me - check system settings and set English keyboard as the default one. (There might be issue in your language settings)